# Как запустить PostgreSQL MacOS?

Tags: postgresql, macos

Пытаюсь поднять PostgreSQL так как по команде `pg_ctl` выдает это:

`pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.`

По инструкции так и должно было быть, но после того как я введу следующую команду, должно было все работать, результат ниже:

`macbook@MacBook-Pro-macbook ~ % pg_ctl -D /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgres start           pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway waiting for server to start....2022-08-07 10:29:23.448 EEST [58711] FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists 2022-08-07 10:29:23.448 EEST [58711] HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 16484) running in data directory "/opt/homebrew/var/postgres"? stopped waiting pg_ctl: could not start server Examine the log output.`

Comment: Возможно, от предыдущего неудачного запуска остался файл `postmaster.pid`. Попробуй удалить его. А вообще, советую всё в докере гонять, один раз потратишь время, чтобы разобраться, но сильно себе облегчишь работу в будущем. Особенно когда понадобятся эксперименты с разными версиями постгриса

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Спасибо, попробую